# Question related to trigonometric identities and ratios

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that  $$\tan \frac{\pi}{30} \tan \frac{7\pi}{30} \tan \frac{11\pi}{30} \tan \frac{13\pi}{30}=1$$

I tried this and i was able to reduce it to $$\cot \frac{\pi}{30} \cot \frac{2\pi}{30} \cot \frac{4\pi}{30} \cot \frac{8\pi}{30}$$

but could not do it any further please tell how to do this after this :)

Comment: we can't use calculator